# Join row with MAX row in another table in Impala?

Tags: sql, impala

I have a simple task to do a join between 'customer' (parent table) and 'order' table (child table) where the joined row of a child table has latest (max) order date value. If Impala were like any SQL engine you could write:

```
select * from customer c
join `order` o on o.customer_id=c.id
and o.id=(
    select o2.id 
    from `order` o2 
    where o2.customer_id=c.id 
    order by o2.order_date 
    desc limit 1
);
```

Obviously impala is different because I simply get the following error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 4:1 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'o2' '.' in expression specification
```

I tried to replace the 'and' with 'where' between the subquery but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a `join` and `aggregation` in the `from` clause:

```
select c.*, o.*
from customer c join
     `order` o
     on o.customer_id = c.id join
     (select customer_id, max(o2.order_date) as maxod
      from `order` o2
      group by customer_id
     ) oo
     on oo.customer_id = o.customer_id and oo.maxod = o.order_date;
```

This assumes that the maximum order date has only one order.  If this is not reasonable, then perhaps you can just use `max(id)` instead of `max(order_date)`.  If the ids are assigned sequentially, then this will do what you want.

You might be able to do what you want using `exists`:

```
select c.*, o.*
from customer c join
     `order` o
     on o.customer_id = c.id
where not exists (select 1
                  from `order` o2
                  where o2.customer_id = o.customer_id and
                        (o2.order_date > o.order_date or
                         (o2.order_date = o.order_date and o2.id > o.id)
                        )
                 );
```